# MongoDB object _id vs compound index

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Been struggling to find some good content about this. What is the better option between:

1. Using an object as _id

   {
     _id: {
       id1
       id2
     }
   }
2. Or create a compound index without changing the auto generated mongo _id

   {
     _id
     id1
     id2
   }

with a

`db.collection.createIndex({id1: 1, id2: 1}, {unique: true})`

Anyone knows some tests or been through this issue before that could help me?

Comment: Either can work fine, but Mongoose [doesn't support](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mongoose-orm/yp_hHanUruo/ffM3WQPD-i8J) a compound `_id`, so if you want to use Mongoose then it's 2.

Comment: Oh, I'm using mongoose. That seems to be a quite an old post though, but can't find nothing on the mongoose documentation about it. I've also read that having a compound _id might have implications on sharding and it's better to leave it as an ObjectID.